# Search webpage for element id

Tags: vb.net, authentication, element, html

How can I create an if statement that will only be carried out if a certain element id is present?

For example, say I login to a website, a logout button will be present which has an assigned elementid. However, if my login is successful, this id would not be present.

The problem I'm having is that if I have a failed login and then write the following:

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Logout").InvokeMember("click")

then I will get an error, because this element does not exist. Is there a way to have a code saying: "If the logout elementid is present on the webpage, then do 'x' else donothing"

Thanks!

Comment: [VB.NET If Then](http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-vbnet)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The problem is that I know how If Then works, but I don't know how to specifically search for what I asked for above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Dim elmLogout as HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Logout")
If (elmLogout IsNot Nothing) Then
    elmLogout.InvokeMember("click")
Else
    ' do other stuff here
EndIf
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked brilliantly :)

Comment: Since you seem to be new to SO: please mark this answer as accepted with the check mark on the left because this marks your question as solved and this is how the underlying reputation system works. You might want to accept that other question of yours, in the same manner, too. :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll d that now